# Possible to check if `@Scheduled` method has finished executing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using `@Scheduled` for one of my methods.

Is there anyway to check if the prior `@Scheduled` task has finished executing?

For example if we have a `@Scheduled` to run every 60 seconds, but sometimes the method takes 80 seconds to complete. Is there anyway to prevent the method from running again unless it has finish executing?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)`

In this case, you shouldn't worry about possible overlapping of tasks because they're executing consistently in one thread.

`ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` uses `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` under the hood, which, in turn, uses `ScheduledExecutorService` (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.html) and [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java)).

And from [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) of `scheduleAtFixedRate` method of `ScheduledExecutorService`, we can clearly see, that

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

Answer (score 0):

`fixedDelay` executes the method with a fixed period of milliseconds between the end of one invocation and the start of the next.

Try with this

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60*1000)
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question

Comment: Actually it does fix OP's problem, but in a lazy way :-).

Using a fixedDelay will guarantee no two executions will overlap. On the other side, it will no longer guarantee an execution every 60 seconds, because the rate will be slower if the method takes a longer time.